# Invalid hook call for react-dom. What can I do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I want to create a global modal component using `redux/toolkit` and manage it globally. When I click the drop-down menu, I create the message I want to display the modal, and when I click the Ok or Cancel button and background, I try to close it.

There is no problem with the event to open the modal, but to close it, send the following error.
Attached is the contents checked according to the error message.

[image]

1. pacakge.json:

   ```json
   "react": "^18.2.0",
   "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
   "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
   ```
2. modalSlice.js

   ```
   import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

   const initialState = {
     modalContent: '',
     isOpen: false,
   }

   export const modalSlice = createSlice({
     name: 'modal',
     initialState,
     reducers: {
       openModal: (state, actions) => {
         const { modalContent } = actions.payload
         const updateState = {
           ...state,
           isOpen: true,
           modalContent,
         }
         return updateState
       },
       closeModal: (state, actions) => {
         console.log(actions)
         const updateState = {
           ...initialState,
         }
         return updateState
       },
     },
   })

   export const { openModal, closeModal } = modalSlice.actions

   export default modalSlice.reducer
   ```

   Modal.js

   ```
   const Modal = () => {
     const dispatch = useDispatch
     const { modalContent } = useSelector((state) => state.modal)
     const modalHandler = (e) => {
       dispatch(closeModal)
     }
     return (
       <>
         <ModalContainer>
           <ModalBack onClick={modalHandler} />
           <ModalContentWrapper>
             <ModalContent>{modalContent}</ModalContent>
             <ModalBtnWrapper>
               <ModalBtn onClick={modalHandler}>취소</ModalBtn>
               <ModalBtn onClick={modalHandler}>확인</ModalBtn>
             </ModalBtnWrapper>
           </ModalContentWrapper>
         </ModalContainer>
       </>
     )
   }
   ```
3. npm ls react

   ```
   wedding_reception@0.1.0 /Users/mary/231014 wedding/mobile/wedding_reception
   ├─┬ @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.2.0
   │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
   ├─┬ @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.5
   │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
   ├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.4.0
   │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
   ├─┬ react-copy-to-clipboard@5.1.0
   │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
   ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
   │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
   ├─┬ react-redux@8.1.1
   │ ├── react@18.2.0 deduped
   │ └─┬ use-sync-external-store@1.2.0
   │   └── react@18.2.0 deduped
   ├─┬ react-router-dom@6.14.1
   │ ├─┬ react-router@6.14.1
   │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
   │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
   ├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
   │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
   ├── react@18.2.0
   └─┬ styled-components@6.0.2
     └── react@18.2.0 deduped
   ```

Comment: On your Modal component, I believe you will need to call the closeModal function. The dispatch method accepts only objects and currently your are passing a function.

dispatch(closeModal())

Comment: @ArditMirashi Thanks for your advice. I fixed it as you said but it still doesn't work.

Comment: const dispatch = useDispatch()

Comment: @NaveenNizam omg.. I'm so embarraseed...... I need to do the basics well.  Thank you so much.

Comment: now is working fine? @mmaryyy

Comment: @NaveenNizam Yes, Perfect! I can't believe it was a simple grammar mistake to think about it all day. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Invalid Hook Call Warning**
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.

*it should be written like that*

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

At first it seems odd how ***not*** calling `useDispatch` could cause an "invalid hook call" error. In the code you have saved a reference to the `useDispatch` hook function and named it `dispatch`, and then later called this function in a nested callback function which is clearly a violations of the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

> ### Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
>
> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or ***nested functions***.
> Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns.

```
const Modal = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch // dispatch is reference to useDispatch function

  const { modalContent } = useSelector((state) => state.modal)

  const modalHandler = (e) => {
    dispatch(closeModal) // e.g. "useDispatch" invoked here
  }

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

## Solution

Invoke the `useDispatch` function correctly at the top level so the *actual* `dispatch` function is callable in a callback function.

```
const Modal = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // dispatch is reference to dispatch function now

  const { modalContent } = useSelector((state) => state.modal);

  const modalHandler = (e) => {
    dispatch(closeModal); // e.g. real "dispatch" invoked here
  }

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```